# PyQt5 - pyuic5 failed with wrong SIP version

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, python-sip

I've faced an issue while using Python3 / PyQt5 on a brand new Qt5 installation

My environment is:

```
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I've installed QT5 and PyQt5 without any problem. When creating the py module from QT UML description, the process fails with a SIP version error.

command:

```
pyuic5 uml/console.ui -o console_ui.py
```

results as:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/PyQt5/uic/pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v8.0 to v8.1 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v10.1
    pyuic5 ui_path/myfile.ui -o ui_path/myfile_ui.py
```

my SIP version is :

```
jeby6372@junon:~$ sip -V
4.15.4
```

SIP 4.15.4 is the lastest version delivered by RiverBank.

I've removed the old QT4 environment so I think there's somewhere a bad link to the corresponding old SIP version.

Numerous similar issues have been posted on the web but none got an valuable answer.(when they're even answered).

Thanks for yor help.

Emmanuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to remove python-sip and install again sip-4.15.4. The packaged python3-sip is out of date for PyQt5